# Simple tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs

How to implement in android simple tabs without any Intents or Views(like in TabHost)?

I need only tab headers and want to listen how tab index changes.

Or advise me how to implement multiposition switches.

UPD: I use api v14 and ActionBar tabs already used for another purpose.

Comment: I tried tabhost, but it not not suitable for me because i can't use TabActivity or show difference activities on different tabs. I have one GridView and tabs need for changing mode of this GridView.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution (in my opinion, of course) would be to simply use three different ImageViews or Buttons to mimick "tabs." You can swap out an "unselected tab" image for a "selected tab" image as necessary.

As far as I am aware, there is no simple way outside of TabHosts and other such solutions requiring Activities, Fragments, or Views for the different tabs.

Comment: What's ugly about it? What is a tab other than a set of a few buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar project a while back where I just needed to listen for tab changes.  Here is a great example from Google:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;

private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

private class TabInfo {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final String tag;
    private final Class<?> clss;
    private final Bundle args;

    public TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _clss, Bundle _args) {
        tag = _tag;
        clss = _clss;
        args = _args;       
            }
}

private class DummyFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    public DummyFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        return v;
    }

}
public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager viewPager) {
    super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());

    mContext = activity;
    mTabHost = tabHost;
    mViewPager = viewPager;

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
    tabSpec.setContent(new DummyFactory(mContext));

    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

    TabInfo tab = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
    mTabs.add(tab);
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    TabInfo tab = mTabs.get(i);
    Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mContext, tab.clss.getName(), tab.args);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "getItem from view pager called returning hash: " + fragment.hashCode());
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mTabs.size();
}

public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
    // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
    // The jerk.
    // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
    // ViewPager.
    TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
    int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
    widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
}

public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

}
 }
```

The relevant parts here is that the adapter implements `TabHost.OnTabChangeListener` and in the body of the constructor, the onTabChangedListener is set accordingly (`mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this)`)

You will also notice the inner class `DummyFactory`

```
private class DummyFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    public DummyFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Which is used in `addTab` to create a content view with `height` and `width` of 0, which allows you to add your actual content under the TabHost in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example

suppose se01,se02 and se03 are three buttons in a horizontal LinearLayout or ScrollView(if you want to support more tabs). So, you could set onClickListeners on each of the Buttons and program them to switch to a specific background (which could show the tab is selected) on click. That's the simplest way to do it. Here's a code snippet, which is quite easy to understand. Hope this helps :-)

```
            //initialize the first button to be 'selected' when the activity is started by a background which is similar to the other buttons but shows the selected button/tab as highlighted.

    se01.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup_full_dark2);
    lastClicked = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ph_s01);//this keeps a track of the last tab/button pressed
    toSe01();// a function which performs the changes to the view with respect to the tab selected

    //Listeners
    se01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v.getId() != lastClicked.getId()) {
                lastClicked
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup_bottom_dark);//changes the background to show the tab is selected
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup_full_dark2);
                lastClicked = se01;
                s.startAnimation(new Animation9());
                toSe01();
                s.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }
    });
    se02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v.getId() != lastClicked.getId()) {
                lastClicked
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup_bottom_dark);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup_full_dark2);
                lastClicked = se02;
                s.startAnimation(new Animation9());
                toSe02();
                s.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }
    });
    se03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v.getId() != lastClicked.getId()) {
                lastClicked
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup_bottom_dark);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup_full_dark2);
                lastClicked = se03;
                s.startAnimation(new Animation9());
                toSe03();
                s.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```